# Laravel/Eloquent: Add missing () in sql statements generated by eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am doing the following request to extract some data from my database. The expected result is wrong because some parenthesis is not well placed in the SQL generated request:

```
$data = Ov::with([
            'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero)
                    ->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            }
        ])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

The dedicated sql generated by Laravel is: (see with Laravel debugbar):

```
select * from `masterequipments` where `masterequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and `macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', 'e8:e7:32:bc:b0:94', 'e8:e7:32:e4:8e:68', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:70', '00:e0:b1:fe:ef:a5', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:a4', '2c:fa:a2:10:79:74', 'e8:e7:32:b9:6d:1d', '00:e0:b1:ee:58:2d', '00:e0:b1:9d:2c:44', '00:e0:b1:b5:e6:00', '00:e0:b1:72:34:86', '00:e0:b1:fe:ee:8d', '00:e0:b1:79:53:52', '00:e0:b1:fe:f0:bd', '00:e0:b1:75:fa:8a', 'e8:e7:32:98:80:22', '00:e0:b1:75:00:8a') or `lastKnownUpAt` <> '0'
```

This is wrong because 2 () are missed. I would like to have:

```
select * from `masterequipments` where `masterequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and (`macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', 'e8:e7:32:bc:b0:94', 'e8:e7:32:e4:8e:68', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:70', '00:e0:b1:fe:ef:a5', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:a4', '2c:fa:a2:10:79:74', 'e8:e7:32:b9:6d:1d', '00:e0:b1:ee:58:2d', '00:e0:b1:9d:2c:44', '00:e0:b1:b5:e6:00', '00:e0:b1:72:34:86', '00:e0:b1:fe:ee:8d', '00:e0:b1:79:53:52', '00:e0:b1:fe:f0:bd', '00:e0:b1:75:fa:8a', 'e8:e7:32:98:80:22', '00:e0:b1:75:00:8a') or `lastKnownUpAt` <> '0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [advanced where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) to accomplish it.

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
            $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
        });
    }
])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

**UPDATE**

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
            $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero);
        })
        ->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
    }
])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

Comment: This piece of code produces the following sql statement: ``select * from `masterequipments` where `masterequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and (`macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', '00:e0:b1:fe:ef:a5', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:a4', '2c:fa:a2:10:79:74', 'e8:e7:32:b9:6d:1d', '00:e0:b1:ee:58:2d', '00:e0:b1:9d:2c:44', '00:e0:b1:b5:e6:00', '00:e0:b1:72:34:86', '00:e0:b1:fe:ee:8d', '00:e0:b1:79:53:52', 'e8:e7:32:98:80:22', '00:e0:b1:75:00:8a')) or (`lastKnownUpAt` <> '0')`` There is yet a problem, it's not exaclty the expected statement. It produce more result as expected

Comment: @wawanopoulos: Check *UPDATE* answer

Comment: Not yet good. Now it produces: ``select * from `masterequipments` where `masterequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and (`macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', 'e8:e7:32:bc:b0:94', 'e8:e7:32:e4:8e:68', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:70')) or `lastKnownUpAt` <> '0'`` instead of expected statement: ``select * from `masterequipments` where `masterequipments`.`id_ov_foreign_key` in ('38') and (`macAddress` in ('e8:e7:32:c1:e6:48', 'e8:e7:32:bc:b0:94', 'e8:e7:32:e4:8e:68', 'e8:e7:32:bc:a7:70') or `lastKnownUpAt` <> '0')``

Comment: Ok, place `->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0')` after `whereIn`

Comment: Hope you got the output?

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to do something like this:

```
    $data = Ov::with([
        'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero);
            })
                ->orWhere(function($query) {
                    $query->where('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
                });
        }
    ])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

This article explain it well http://laraveldaily.com/and-or-and-brackets-with-eloquent/